# Does a tree absorb carbon dioxide only by its outer growth ring?

Tags: photosynthesis, trees

I'm trying to understand how the amount of carbon-14 isotope is changing in a tree trunk, so I would like to clarify if a tree absorbs carbon dioxide only by its outer growth ring in a current year of its life.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the [Tour] to learn about this site. As an apparent non-native English speaker, I advise you to do what I do when writing in a foreign language. Run your text — especially the title — through a spelling and grammar checker before posting. Even if you are highly intelligent and your science is good, simple errors of grammar give a bad impression.

Comment: I think you will find that the CO2 is absorbed at the leaf, converted into sugars and then may be stored as carbon. So no Co2 at the trunk.

Comment: Do you actually mean to ask about CO2, or about carbon-14?

Comment: Thanks to everyone and sorry for my English, I'll try to be more careful with grammar next time.

Comment: @BryanKrause, I'm interested in carbon-14. I just know that CO2 contains carbon-14 at a constant percentage.

Comment: the outer ring stores carbon from the last growt season but the leaves store a lot too.